# Use c# application (TcpListener) as a web server

Tags: c#, webserver, portforwarding, tcplistener

I have been trying to do this for a while. I'm using the MSDN example for the TCPListener, being able to connect to it within the same newtork (i.e: from a terminal on my mobile phone).

I also understand that this works because of them being connected to the same router; I have entered to my router configurations and forwarded port 13450, which is the port I'm using on my TCP Listener constructor, to my computer's IP Address, and I've also submitted Windows firewall rules to not block this port for any external application.

After saving the port forwarding, I change IP Address on my C# Console Application to my router's IP (Default Gateway)
I've tried from hyperterminal on windows or from a terminal on my mobile phone to connect to my application (Using my router's IP and the corresponding port), but have never been able to manage this.

I would really appreciate help for this, as I cannot encounter a useful solution searching on Google

Thanks.

This is the code

```
  Int32 port = 13450;
  IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("189.148.67.13");

  // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
  server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

  // Start listening for client requests.
  server.Start();

  // Buffer for reading data
  Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
  String data = null;

  // Enter the listening loop.
  while(true) 
  {
    Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

    // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
    // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();            
    Console.WriteLine("Connected!");}
```

The IP is the public IP for my router; and on its config i've forwarded port 13450 to my local computer. Thanks

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Normally problems like this are related to how you've setup your port forwarding.  It's difficult to say anything else because you haven't posted your server code.

Comment: Are you sure the devices you are using were outside the local/wifi network?

Comment: _"I change IP Address on my C# Console Application to my router's IP (Default Gateway)"_ do you mean the IP your tcp listener should listen on? I don't think this can work. And it sounds more like a general network question which would be off topic on so. But maybe some code snippets can bring clarity to the problem.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the responses